# Can I still use my passport if it has loose stitching?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens

My Indian passport has got loose stitching; will it be considered damaged? I have a trip to Singapore coming up in 7-10 days. Will this create any problems at Immigration? While the stitching is worn, all the other parts, like photo and my details, are not damaged.

[image: photo of loose stiching]

Comment: Do you have an Android phone with NFC? Can it still be read electronically? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.innovalor.nfciddocshowcase

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I've never heard of a passport inspector refusing a passport because the NFC communication was broken.  Have you?

Comment: @phoog I think Stephan might have meant a working RFID will reassure the inspector that it is all genuine, negating that loose stitches might otherwise cause suspicion of forgery.

Comment: Yes, what user16259 said.

Comment: @Branczyk Indian Passports do not have NFC technology. What to do next?

Comment: Karan can you please tell us if the booklet has completely separated from the passport cover itself or it's still sticking somehow with the cover? Because from the photo, it seems like that the booklet has completely came off from the main binding cover.