# Is my passport damaged and can't be used for visas and travel?

Tags: passports

This morning, I went to submit my documents at the VFS office. The VFS officer informed me that my passport looks damaged. Until she said that, I never noticed anything abnormal. My pages are holding good, my cover is intact. The only thing I noticed was there is a bit of gap between first and second page at the top.

I went ahead and submitted my passport, with an undertaking letter. Hopefully, my visa will come through fine.

Does this count as damaged? In case my visa is approved, is it advisable to apply for new passport before travel?

[image]

Comment: Unlike those other questions, this one provides a photograph. As the higher quality question, it should be answered and the others closed to *it*.

Comment: Hmm, I think I've seen several questions recently claiming bad stitching on Indian passports, some of them with photographs where (just like this one) I don't think the stitching actually looks out of the ordinary. -- e.g. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116193/can-i-still-use-my-passport-if-it-has-loose-stitching

Comment: **Please note** the VFS don't have "officers". They have clerks. They're a glorified courier service, and have no say at all in deciding applications.

Comment: Well said  Henning Makholm.. They behave like officers but do worse job than a clerk.. First they said my photo was bad, as i wore a black framed eyeglasses which is not accepted and asked me to get a new one (within VFS complex). Then took lot of time to collect documents and then came up with this.. Totally spoiled my day !!